# Find $q$ such that $[q[qn]]+1=[q^2n]$ for $n=1,2,\dotsc$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, ceiling-and-floor-functions, golden-ratio

> Find $q>0$ such that 
>   $$[q[qn]]+1=[q^2n],\qquad n=1,2,\dotsc$$ 
>   where $[x]$ is the integer-valued function.

In fact, if $q=\frac{\sqrt{5}+1}2$, then $q^2-q=1$, so we can verify $$[q[qn]]+1=[q^2n],\qquad n=1,2,\dotsc$$
and I believe $q=\frac{\sqrt{5}+1}2$ is the only solution of the equation.

Now I have only proved $1.6125\leq q\leq 1.6190$, it still has a long way to go!

Comment: How do you define $[x]$?

Comment: @Eufisky I have edited your question to make it clearer, I hope you don't mind the changes. Could you also clarify what you mean by "integer-valued function"? Are you referring to the [floor function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_and_ceiling_functions)?

Comment: Maybe let $n$ be one of the denominators of the continued fraction for $q$ and see what happens.

Comment: @LucaBressan yes

Answer (score 4):

First, let's reduce this to a question about fractional parts. First we rewrite the equation as follows:
$$[q^2n-q\{qn\}]+1=q^2n-\{q^2n\}$$
Or, equivalently,
$$q^2n-\{q^2n\}-1 \leq q^2n-q\{qn\}<q^2n-\{q^2n\}$$
Then, making cancellations, we reduce to
$$\{q^2n\}+1 \geq q\{qn\} >\{q^2n\}.$$
Now, we can try to get into trouble: The reason this works for the golden ratio is that $\{\varphi^2n\}=\{\varphi n\}$, which makes this simpler. Note also that, if $q$ is rational written as $q=a/b$, then setting $n=b^2$ violates right inequality, so $q$ must be irrational. Then, assuming $q$ is irrational, our condition is equivalent to the following (closed) condition:
$$\{q^2n\}+1 \geq q\{qn\} \geq \{q^2n\}.$$

Note now, all that matters is the set $S=\{(\{q^2n\},\{qn\}):n\in\mathbb N\}$ and $q$ itself. We require the following hold for all $(x,y)\in S$: 
$$x+1 \geq qy\geq x.$$
Now, note that if we define $\bar S$ as the closure of $S$, this condition must still hold on $\bar S$.

It turns out - from either casework or knowing something about diophantine approximation, observing that $q$ is irrational - that $\bar S$ will always either be a set of the form $\{(\{\alpha\},\{c\alpha\}):\alpha\in \mathbb R\}$, where $c$ is rational (and where we take the closure of this set in $[0,1]\times [0,1]$) or must be all of $[0,1]\times [0,1]$.

Observe first that $(1,1)\in \bar S$ in any case, so we get that $2\geq q\geq 1$, where we can make these inequalities strict since $q$ is irrational. Then, observe that if $(x,0)\in \bar S$, then $x=0$, since otherwise the condition would be violated. Then, suppose that $(1,y)$ is in $\bar S$; we get here that $qy\geq 1$. Since $q<2$, this implies $y>1/2$, but unless $y=1$, we would also get that $(1,1-y)$ is in $\bar S$ from looking at the possible cases for $\bar S$ - but $1-y<1/2$. Thus, it must be that $y=1$ in this case.

Therefore, we have established that the intersection of $\bar S$ with the boundary of the square $[0,1]\times [0,1]$ is just $(0,0)$ and $(1,1)$. In particular, this analysis gives us that $\bar S=\{(x,x):0\leq x \leq 1\}$. This can only happen if $\{q^2\}=\{q\}$. Then, finally, this occurs for solutions to $q^2-q-n$. The solution to this is $q=\frac{1\pm\sqrt{1+4n}}{2}$. Then, the only solution for $q$ in the interval $(1,2)$ is $q=\varphi$, so this is the only number with this property.

Comment: How can we get $(1,1-y)\in \bar{S}$ from $(1,y)\in \bar{S}$ ?

Comment: @MathRoc If you believe the claim that the set is the closure of the set $\{(\{\alpha\}, \{c\alpha\}):\alpha\in\mathbb R\}$ for some $c$, you can first note that $(0,y)$ is in $\bar S$ if and only if $(1,y)$ is in $\bar S$ (since that is where the line "wraps around"). Also, for $0<y<1$, we have that $(0,y)$ is in $\bar S$ if and only if $(0, 1-y)$ is, since $\{-c\alpha \} = 1-\{c\alpha\}$ so long as $c\alpha$ isn't rational.

Comment: Thanks. I wonder why $\alpha\in \mathbb{N}$. Now that the $q-$ formula holds for natural $n$, I think $\bar{S}$ should be $\{({\alpha},{c\alpha}): \alpha>0\}$.

Comment: @MathRoc The trick there is to see that, for any $\varepsilon > 0$, there are infinitely many $n$ so that $qn$ and $q^2n$ are within $\varepsilon$ of an integer (you can do this, for instance, by noting that $S$ is infinite, so has elements arbitrarily close to each other - and then looking at the difference between their indices $n$). But if $m<n$, then $\{q(n-m)\}$ is close to $1-\{qm\}$ (since $qn$ is near an integer) and $\{q^2(n-m)\})$ is close to $1-\{q^2m\}$ (since $qn^2$ is near an integer). There's some details to handle, but positivity turns out not to be relevant to $\bar S$.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I got it.

Comment: I think it's difficult to show that $\bar{S}=\{(x,x): 0\leqslant x\leqslant 1\}$. I tried to turn it out by $(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2})\in \bar{S}$, but it failed. So, could you show me the details ?

Comment: Could you the details of $\bar{S}=\{(x,x): 0\leqslant x\leqslant 1\}$

Comment: So I think the last part is the most difficult.