# Deriving $q$ from an identity about floor function.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

> **Question.** The equality
> $$\big[q[qn]\big]+1=\big[q^2 n\big]$$
> holds for $n\in \mathbb{N}^*$, iff $q=\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}$.

It's evident that $q\in (1,2)\backslash\mathbb{Q}$, and
$$\langle q^2n\rangle+1>q\langle qn\rangle>\langle q^2 n\rangle,$$
where $[x],\langle x\rangle$ are the integer part, fractional part of $x$ respectively, such as
$$[1.4]=1,\ \langle 1.4\rangle=\frac{2}{5}.$$

The proof can be found here [enter link description here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2206642/find-q-such-that-qqn1-q2n-for-n-1-2-dotsc?noredirect=1).

We define
$$S:=\left\{\left(\langle q^2 n\rangle,\langle qn\rangle\right):n\geqslant 1\right\}.$$
It implies that
$$x+1\geqslant qy\geqslant x,\ \forall (x,y)\in \bar{S}.$$
In the following link, we want to prove the **Question** by verifying
$$\bar{S}=\{(x,x):0\leqslant x\leqslant 1\}.\tag{1.1}$$
If it works, we have $\langle q^2\rangle=\langle q\rangle$, which completes the proof.

However, it's difficult to verify the fact $(1.1)$. I just get $(0,0),(1,1)\in \bar{S}$, which can be found in the comments of the following link.

I wonder how to solve the **Question** in other ways, or just how to verify the fact $(1.1)$.

Any help will be appreciated.